# Selecting all items of a subset by id

Tags: c#, linq

I have bought items and equipped items, I need to get the bought items that are in equipped items. I tried this but it gave me both item 1 and 2 when `x.Id == 2`.

```
user.BoughtItems.Where(x => equippedItems.Any(any => any.Id == x.Id))
```

The test was performed using:

BoughtItems has 2 items. One with Id = 1, Two with Id = 2.

EquippedItems has 1 item with Id = 2.

I was expecting a result of one item (from BoughtItems) with id = 2.

Comment: Are these items of same type? If so you could use Intersect.

Comment: @epitka I think you mean Intersect =D

Comment: @epitka: They are same type, but are different objects (instances) but with same Id.

Comment: @Fabricio: If you have Equals and GetHashCode overridden then it does not matter.

Comment: @NeerajDubey, this was already written by Alden, you don't need to paste it in the comments as well

Comment: @epitka: I dont have. Should I? I'm not sure about what to do inside these methods, expecialy GetHashCode. Can you give an example?

Comment: @Fabricio are you sure that your second sequence doesn't have both Id's 1 and 2 ? Because otherwise what you have should work.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov yes, it has 1 item with id = 2. BoughtItem has 2 items, with id 1 and 2.

Comment: @Fabricio: Well, should you or not I don't know. What are these objects? Are they domain objects? Are the two instances of the same id same object or not?  Too many questions before answer can be given. If you are using NHibernate then you should override them. Here is the link on how to do it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx

Comment: @Fabricio Does it have both items or just a single one ? Because if both sequences have 2 items with the same id's, it will return 2 results therefore you're observing the correct results

Comment: @epitka im using asp net mvc 4 with entityframework. They are 2 instances with same id.

Comment: @Fabricio: Don't know how EF works, but are you sure that they are two different instances? They very well might be the same, I would think that EF implements IdentityMap and would return you same instance during one session request. We  override on all our domain objects.

Comment: equippedItems comes from client and it is just a Bind object.

Comment: @epitka: I overriden Equals() and put Id comparition there and Intersect() worked. What am I suppose todo with GetHashCode() ?

Comment: @Fabricio: Make sure you classes implements IEquatable<T> interface and then just override GetHashCode also. In the link I posted couple of comments about you have complete examle.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var equippedIds = equippedItems.Select(x => x.Id).ToHashSet();
var boughtAndEquipped = user.BoughtItems.Where(x => equippedIds.Contains(x.Id));
```

**EDIT:** forgot that `.ToHashSet()` isn't built in because I have a handful of linq extensions that I include in every project. Here it is:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return new HashSet<T>(source);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't find ToHashSet()

Comment: @Fabricio I don't know what happens on your side but your code works GREAT for me. The logic is very clear that it should work and testing has proved it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] BoughtItems = { 1, 2 };
    int[] equippedItems = { 1 };
    var result = BoughtItems.Where(x => equippedItems.Any(any => any == x));
    foreach (var el in result)
        Console.WriteLine(el);
}
```

**Result**: 1

Can you show what you have and what you need, because now i can't see the problem you talking about.

By the way, this one has the same result:

```
class Itemm
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Itemm> BoughtItems = new List<Itemm>() { new Itemm { Id = 1 }, new Itemm { Id = 2 } };
    List<Itemm> equippedItems = new List<Itemm>() { new Itemm { Id = 1 } };
    var result = BoughtItems.Where(x => equippedItems.Any(any => any.Id == x.Id));
    foreach (var el in result)
        Console.WriteLine(el.Id);
}
```

**Result**: 1

Answer (score 0):

Just use a join:

```
boughtItems.Join(equippedItems,b=>b.Id,eq=>eq.Id,(b,eq)=>b.Id);
```

This will return the ID's. If you want both items you can create a Tuple off of them by replacing the result selector **(b,eq)=>b.Id** with **Tuple.Create**

Then you can access the bought and equipped related items using the "Item1" and "Item2" properties of the returned instances, respectively.